# MobileFirst 8.0 - call protected adapter from WLResourceRequest

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I tried to invoke a protected javascript resource adapter in MFP 8.0 cordova app (with mfp plugin also installed), without any specific security setted. Below the configuration used:

**adapter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mfp:adapter name="AccountAdapter"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:mfp="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
         xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

<displayName>AccountAdapter</displayName>
<description>AccountAdapter</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <domain>mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com</domain>
        <port>443</port>
        <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
        <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
        <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
    </connectionPolicy>
</connectivity>

<procedure name="getUser"/>
```

**javascript app code**

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("adapters/AccountAdapter/getUser", WLResourceRequest.GET);
        resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", "[1]");
        resourceRequest.send().then(success, loadFailure);
```

but the response was

```
worklight.js:10192 GET http://localhost:6015/mfp/api/adapters/AccountAdapter/getUser?params=%5B1%5D 401 (Unauthorized)
```

The test was made in Mobile Browser Simulator, for iOS platform.

I remember that, in previous versions of MFP, calls to adapters negotiate automatically the token to access to protected resource.

Is it still possible to do that, without sophisticate the authorization process?

If no, what is necessary to make call to a protected resource?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation about security: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/#disabling-protection

Have you tried disabling security?
In JavaScript adapters add the `secured` attribute and set its value to `false`.

For example:

```
<procedure name="deleteUser" secured="false">
```

Comment: Yes, I did and it worked...But it's not what I want to do. In MFP 7.1 I made calls to adapter without specify the property "wl_unprotected" and the framework negotiated automatically the token to be used for procedure call... Is this approach still valid?

Comment: No. You need to read about the security framework in v8.0. It has changed.

Comment: Ok. I followed the section of documentation available at this link https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/#javascript-adapters, because I want to protect resources without configure a complex security check, but it isn't working. I can't understand how does it work. Can you provide an example of that?